# Deferred deeplink with Adjust does not work if app was not installed

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink

I have an **Adjust** URI with for my app "*myapp*" for the method "*mymethod*" which calls 3 parameters: *param1, param2, param3*

as you can see here:

https://app.adjust.com/123abc?deep_link=myapp%3A%2F%2Fmymethod%3Fparam1%3D3.5516%26param2%3D3.5629%26param3%3D2016-10-16

If my app was already installed, everything works very fine and those 3 parameters are then aleady set on app start into the proper TextEdits already.

If my app was not installed, the Playstore is called, with the invitation to download the app. I have to press in PlayStore *Open* to start the app then, to start the app. But the 3 parameters were not set on startup?

EDIT: As you can see in the trailer that my **deeplink** is not online and the scheme has the form:

```
myapp://mymethod?param1=3.5516&param2=3.5629&param3=2016-10-16
```

Those parameters are taken over hand handed to this app. That means When I call that URI *myapp* starts with those paramters already set in the TextEdit's.

**BUT** when *myapp* was not installed,  PlayStore is opened with *myapp* ready to be installed. Starting the *myapp* afterwards does not take over the parameters into that app (as in calling that URI with preinstalled *myapp*)

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Is your deep link path immediately accessible after install? If there is a signup/login process that blocks access to that URI path, this could be why ([Adjust docs](https://docs.adjust.com/en/deeplinking/#deferred-deeplinking)).

Deferred deep linking is not a core part of the Adjust platform, so flexibility is somewhat limited. If you need a more comprehensive solution, you could check out [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). The Branch platform gives you significantly more deferred deep linking options, and also integrates with Adjust to synchronize all your data.

Comment: When myapp would not be installed, and I create and call a branch.io deeplink with preset parameters similar as above , would it open myapp with preset parameters AFTER a fresh PlayStore installation?

Comment: And yes, the deeplink scheme myapp://mymethod?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c schould be accessible by app side

Comment: Yes, a Branch deep link would return those parameters to you instantly, even after a fresh install from the Play Store. I have heard of delays in deferred returns with Adjust, so it's possible you would get your parameters back a few minutes later. Obviously not very helpful for your usecase...